# Infinite Scroll + Swipe.js

Tags: javascript, slider, swipe, infinite-scroll

Background: 
I'm making a portfolio site utilising both Swipe.js and Infinite Ajax Scroll (JQ).

Problem:
When the content from extra pages is loaded into the current page, it is not processed by the already-loaded Swipe.js script.  This means that the new content doesn't have it's mark-up changed (needed for the swipe functionality to work).

I think I need to get the Swipe.js script to fire after each page re-load.  Would that fix it?   Please explain this to me like I'm an 8yr old.  JS is not a strong suit...

Demo:
http://hatchcreative.co.nz/tomo

You can see that as the page loads new content, the buttons on either side of the sliders no longer work.

Comment: Also - for bonus points - if anyone knows how to remove the #home/ #about bit from the url, you'd totally make my day!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, after the images are loaded you have to create a new Swipe instance on these new elements (as they weren't there at the beginning, when the page was loaded).
Based on the docs of infinite scroll you can use [`onRenderComplete`](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll#onrendercomplete).

So you had your `jQuery.ias` constructor like this:

```
jQuery.ias({
  // ... your settings...
  onRenderComplete: function(items) {
    $(items).each(function(index, element) {
      new Swipe(element);
    });
  }
});
```

This should work this way somehow, but I am not exactly sure; I haven't worked with these libraries yet.

**Edit**:
After some more inspection of your code, I saw you had some inline click handler like: `onclick='two.prev();return false;'`.

You need to remove this and add your `onclick` handle in the same `onRenderComplete` function.

```
onRenderComplete: function(items) {
  var swipe;
  $(items).each(function(index, element) {
    swipe = new Swipe(element);
  });

  // find tags with the class 'forward' inside the current element and add the handler
  $(element).find('.forward').on('click', function() {
     swipe.next();
  });
  // ... also for previous
}
```

---

*By the way*: Usually you should provide a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) with your important code parts, so it's easier for us to get the problem, and the question is not getting obsolote when the linked page changes.